# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] on Glass XE16 KitKat

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have a Glass GDK app ([open-source on Github](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/onebusaway-android/tree/glass)) that works fine on XE12.

I got the XE16 update yesterday, and now when I run `gradlew installDebug` to deploy to Glass, I get the message:

> :onebusaway-android:installDebug
>           pkg: /data/local/tmp/onebusaway-android-debug-unaligned.apk
>                                                                  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Here are the changes I've made to update to XE16:

1. I've changed my `compileSdkVersion` to `"Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"`
2. I've updated the `gdk.jar` in the `/libs` folder to the file from `<android-sdk>/add-ons/addon-google_gdk-google-19/libs`
3. Added `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>` to manifest for pre-production voice commands

(I actually made these changes prior to receiving the XE16 update myself, based on reports of it failing on XE16 from others - so I can confirm that with the above changes the app still works fine on XE12).

I'm using [this third-party progress bar library](https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar), but from what I can tell from the release notes nothing has changed with the `GestureDetector` or `Gesture` Glass classes, which are the only Glass-specific classes it relies on.

My Glassware is an immersive Activity, so I'm not relying on TimelineManager or Cards (which changed in XE16).

**EDIT**

I've tried removing the third-party progress bar, but that doesn't seem to have any affect - still the same error.

I've also updated to Android Studio 0.5.5, no luck deploying from there either (as opposed to running `gradlew installDebug` from command-line).  Also tried removing `/libs/gdk.jar` since this isn't required in Android Studio 0.5.5, still no change.

Comment: What development environment are you using?  (ADT?)

Comment: I'm running Gradle from command-line with `gradlew installDebug`, but I'm also trying from within Android Studio.  Neither work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any `<uses-library>` elements that aren't supported by Glass in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you must include the `android:required="false"` attribute, or remove the element completely, for your app to install on XE16.  This is a change in behavior from XE12.

According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html):

> If `<uses-library>` element is present and its `android:required` attribute is set to true, the `PackageManager` framework won't let the user install the application unless the library is present on the user's device...The default android:required value is "true".

I borrowed code from a normal Android app for my Glass app, and I had a leftover element buried in the manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

Since I didn't include the `android:required="false"`, XE 16 is correctly preventing the app from installing.

Apparently XE12 didn't enforce this, and installed the app anyway.

After either adding the `android:required="false"`attribute:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
              android:required="false"/>
```

...or removing this `<uses-library>` element completely, the app now installs correctly on XE16.

Comment: FYI: this error might be related to this message while installing the apk: `The installation package uses a shared directory that does not exist. The package may not be compatible with the system. Error code: -9`.