# Google Maps Library is not working in Google Glass after update to XE16

Tags: android, google-maps, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a Glass GDK app that uses Google Maps which works fine on XE12. But after update to XE 16 it doesn't allow me to install and gives me [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] , for this I found below solution by which I am able to install.

[Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] on Glass XE16 KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135957/failure-install-failed-missing-shared-library-on-glass-xe16-kitkat)

Now , the problem is that when I am trying to execute class that uses Google Maps( extends MapActivty ) it gives me below exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26103): Process: com.pyronyx.glass.example, PID: 26103
E/AndroidRuntime(26103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activ
ity ComponentInfo{com.pyronyx.glass.example/com.example.card_menu.GpsManager}: j
ava.lang.RuntimeException: stub
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:2285)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(Activit
yThread.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1236)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:5061)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
15)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(26103): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(Un
known Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at com.example.card_menu.GpsManager.<init>(GpsMa
nager.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method
)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instr
umentation.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2152)
E/AndroidRuntime(26103):        ... 11 more
```

Please help me in this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webview for displaying map as browser.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the location capability, you can, as a workaround, use the built-in [Nav Glassware](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware). You cannot use Maps on Glass. If you tried to use Maps, I'd assume that is the reason for your Exception above.

Comment: Is there any alternative for it ?
Navigation is different to maps.